# How to find travel deals for a very specific area?

Tags: budget, hotels

It's relatively easy to find a flight and a hotel in a kind of bundle deal for any particular city.

But, I'm on business and I'd ideally like to find a hotel in the specific area of my business trip (say, a conference center) so I can avoid the price of a vehicle.

Is there a travel website that will help me with this? Or, for example, should I just call the hotels in the area?

Comment: Which specific area?

Comment: In the abstract this is hard to answer. For some places, the answer is to stay further out and get a bus in. Others, you want to ring round. As @fredley says, what''s the location for your question?

Comment: Welcome to travel.se! Please rephrase your question for a problem you are actually having. I.e. if there's a specific area you want to find travel deals in, just name it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use momondo.com. They aggregate results from other travel agencies and they offer a nice map search feature. Find your city on the map, find the conference venue and then look for hotels nearby.

Answer (score 1):

I use booking.com. What I really like is that you can cancel any booking up to 24 hours before arriving.

Another way is to use google maps. First locate the venue, select the appropriate scale and then type hotel in search field. The surrounding hotels will popup around your conference venue.